# How to get a list of the GET/POST request performed by a wpf webclient

Tags: html, wpf, vb.net, .net

I'm developing a WPF application in VB.net, as said in the title of the question I'm trying to have a list of the GET or the POST request performed by the Net.webclient, the result that I want is something like the firefox web console, any suggestion?
(sorry for my bad english but i'm italian)

Answer (score 0):

Blackfox,

I recommend using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It captures the traffic to and from your machine. Hope that helps!

-sf